# MongoDB .NET - Snapshot read without replica set?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I'm currently using a standalone MongoDB instance and would like to use snapshot read concern so that I can get a consistent view of the data across multiple reads within a read-only transaction.

From the research I've done it looks like client sessions/transactions are only allowed when MongoDB is configured as a replica set, but I can't find anything from the MongoDB devs that explicitly says why this is the case.

Why does this limitation exist, and is there a way around this so that transactions can be used against a standalone box? I understand I can configure a single-node replica but my use-case doesn't warrant the need for replicas so I would like to avoid the extra complexity.

Comment: it's server restriction since standalone doesn't support oplog. In other words, standalone setup is not recommended approach for production setup

Comment: It just seems like an arbitrary limitation, almost poor design, that you don't get an op-log with a single node...